# How to reflect and then rotate a particular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We can think of matrices as performing actions graphically. Here we’ll
limit our attention to R^2, but similar results would hold in higher dimensional
spaces.

(a) Construct a matrix R such that the vector Rx = y is the vector x after
being rotated 90 degrees counterclockwise about the origin. Demonstrate that
your matrix performs as promised.

Solving part (a) as follows: using a basis E1 = [1;0] transposed and E2 =[0;1] transposed. So the basis would be [AE1, AE2]...using this basis to solve for R, the solution should look like R= [0 -1; 1 0] (Entered as if in MatLab)

Does this solution look correct, and could someone clarify how the basis can be applied to to RE1=E2 so that is looks like RE2=-E1?

And if so, how would I go about using the basis to solve the following questions:

(b) Construct a matrix S such that the vector Sx = y is the vector x =[x1, x2]^T after being reflected across the line x1 = x2. Demonstrate that your
matrix performs as promised.

(c) Construct a matrix T such that Tx = y is a vector x = [x1, x2]^T after
first being reflected across the line x1 = x2 and then being rotated 90 degrees
counterclockwise about the origin. Demonstrate that your matrix performs as
promised. Be sure to explain for thought process.

Comment: What do you know about the columns of a matrix?

Comment: This is not a place for dumping great mounds of undigested homework problems.

Comment: Was hoping to gain some insight regarding where one would start with a problem like this... Any help is more than appreciated.

Comment: Where you start is you read the paragraph that explains why the question was put on hold, and you try to edit the question with that paragraph in mind.

Comment: Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:** We note that, when rotated $90^\circ$, the vector $(1,0)^T$ is sent to $(0,1)^T$.  So, the first column of $R$ is $(0,1)^T$.  Similarly, the second column is the destination of $(0,1)^T$, which in this case is $(-1,0)^T$.

Apply a similar process for the second part: our columns are always the destinations of $(1,0)^T$ and $(0,1)^T$ respectively.

(c) and (d) are both about matrix multiplication.  Be sure to multiply the matrices in the correct order!  Alternatively, use geometry to find the destinations of $(1,0)^T$ and $(0,1)^T$ directly.

Comment: Why would one take the destination (0,1) and continue to rotate it another 90 degrees to find the second column?

Comment: @M. Steven we're not using $(0,1)$ because it's the destination: we always look at $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$.  For example: with the rotation by $180^\circ$, we would find that
$$
(1,0) \mapsto (-1,0)\\
(0,1) \mapsto (0,-1)
$$
So the columns of the matrix are $(-1,0)$ and $(0,-1)$ in that order.

Comment: @M.Steven you might find [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYB8IZa5AuE) helpful.

Comment: Couldn't have found a better explanation ^... Thank you. I am all set